# In camerax, video capture, preview view and image analyzer usecases not working together

Tags: video-capture, preview, android-camerax, analyzer, android-12

While using Camerax, when I combine video capture, preview view and image analyzer usecases, preview becomes blank for android 12, but working on 11 and 13.

```
cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                    val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        owner,
                        cameraSelector,
                        videoCapture,
                        previewView,
                        imageAnalyzer
                    )
```

but after removing the image analyzer, preview was visible.

Comment: Which version of CameraX are you using? 1.2.* or 1.3*?